# Wavelet through the lens of Harmonic analysis

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

I need some references for starting to study about wavelet. I have enough information about abstract Harmonic analysis.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try  http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9783540242598 for a group theoretic aproach

Comment: Could you expand a bit on which type of wavelet analysis you are thinking of? It is quite a big and diverse field nowadays.