# Wavelet reference for PDE

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, wavelets

Can anyone recommend a very readable introduction to wavelets for use in theoretical PDE/harmonic analysis? I'm frustrated with the account in Lemarie-Rieusset's Navier-Stokes book since he provides little motivation. I've been told [Daubechies' 1992 book](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611970104) is good. [This similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456409/wavelet-through-the-lens-of-harmonic-analysis) only produced one response and it looks much to abstract for my purpose. Unfortunately many books that sound promising (eg. [Wavelets Made Easy](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-6006-0)) are intended for an applied audience.

Comment: How about Boggess' book? It's a decently rigorous treatment, but it's not super heady book. Or you could read Mallat's book. He's an expert and extremely pedagogical.

Comment: @CameronWilliams This looks nice, I'll take a look.